# Getting code formatting error on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, code-formatting, error-message

[image]

I don't know what is wrong with my indentation but it's not taking this input from me. I get the error:

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: The original Stack Overflow question:
[Getting a debug error using the function error()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71728591).

Comment: I tried to use your original Markdown (to repost at Stack Overflow, and press *Review your question*), but I could not reproduce the error message.
My best guess is that someone has changed how the filter works since April 3, 2022,
when you posted your question here.
Otherwise, I don't know why the error message cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Ordered lists should use numbers (1, 2, 3) not letters (a, b, c)
2. If you want to indent text the next line after a list item, add two spaces at the end of the list item, then on the next line, add three spaces, then the text, i.e.:

   ```
   1. Apple
   2. Banana  
      Plátano
   ```
3. Add a space after `>`
4. For file paths instead of putting them as quotes put them as code i.e.

   Instead of

   ```
   >C:\...
   ```

   use

   ```
       C:\...
   ```

   or use code fences

   ````
   ```
   C:\...
   ```
   ````

Reference

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked. I was stuck at this stupid question for like an hour

Comment: Re *"add two spaces at the end"*: Or a space and a backslash. This will avoid problems with tools that remove trailing white space.